# Custom Kendo Grid order with editable popup

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please see this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/JPgjd/) for clarification.

In the fiddle, I want the popup editor fields to be in the order they're currently in: `ID, Name, Type, Quantity, Notes`. But in the grid itself, I'd like: `Quantity, Type, Name`.

Is separating the grid and the popup editor's field ordering possible? Ideally without creating more complicated templates (this example is simple, but in my real-world app, I'm dealing with 20+ fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is the one that you define in `columns` section of the Grid definition so just change the order as in : http://jsfiddle.net/JPgjd/4/

```
columns: [
    {
        command: ["edit"],
        title: "&nbsp",
        width: "95px"
    },
    { field: "quantity", title: "Qty" },
    { field: "type", title: "Type" },
    { field: "id", title: "ID", hidden: true },
    { field: "name", title: "Name" },
    { field: "notes", title: "Notes", hidden: true }
]
```

Remember that the order also apply when editing so `hidden` fields are displayed in the order defined in columns (hidden in a column definition applies only to grid not to editing form).

Comment: That works for changing grid order, but it also rearranges order in the popup editor. I'd like to be able to customize order for each, so grid order is Qty, Type, Name and editor order is Id, Name, Type, Qty, Notes. It's a strange and probably not a very common scenario. I may need to use templates.

Comment: Then use a [`editable.template`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-editable.template). Need an example?

Comment: Yep - I guess that's the best approach. No example needed, that link is enough. Thank you.